# Qt Signal over writing previous

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, signals-slots

I have two classes, Class1, Class2 (Singleton), both use QT signals & slots. Each class contain instance of separate class Message: Msg1, Msg2 respectively

Class1: Signal-X from Msg1 is connected to Class1 slotX

Class2: Signal-X from Msg2 is connected to Class2 slotY.

When Class1 is instantiated, the constructor causes two messages being sent to Message Class, which will then cause Signal-X emitted by Message Class. Two messages means Signal emitted twice (with different parameter data). I have used Qt:AutoConnection during the signal and slot connection in both Class1, Class2.

Normally everything work normally as expected. But Some times I notice, Class1::SlotX() is not getting fired twice, where as Class2::SlotY() is fired twice!! The signal source is same in both cases!!!

1. Is it possible that when Class1 Event loops is busy, 2nd Signal-X overwrite the 1st Signal-X  before Class1::SlotX() is used? For Singleton class Class2, there is no problem. The Class2::SlotY() is fired twice always.
2. Is the QT signal & slot connection immediate after Connect()? Or does it take time after which only signal and slot are connected?

Can some one please help...
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you put a printf() call directly above your "emit signal" line, and verified that your signals are actually being emitted twice, and that these emits are in fact being called after their corresponding connect() calls?

Comment: Also, when are your objects constructed?  If they are static, and constructed before main(), that might be an issue.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I can confirm Singleton Class2::SlotY() is being called twice, which means signal is emitted twice!! But not the Class1::SlotX() :-(

Comment: Maybe you connected both signals to SlotY by mistake?  If you post the code people might be able to spot an error in it.

Comment: hard to tell. some code maybe? (please not the whole project, just minimalistic declaration, where the connect happens and where you instantiate the objects) ;)

Comment: without the code it's really hard to tell, but I doubt that there is errros in the qt code for the signal / slot mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an attempt to answer to your question 2.

Depending if your Class1 Class2 and Message classes are or not in the same thread, Qt::AutoConnection will result in different behaviour.

If both are on the same thread, it results in a direct connection, so the slot is called directly, as a callback, without invoking the event loop.

If not on the same thread, it is called indirectly through the event loop, so as a matter of fact you have no guarantee when the receiver's slot is executed.

For q1, as stated by Jeremy Friesner, code sample is needed